Is there any way to tokenize a string to a macro?
In python, there is a function eval() to run a string. For example, if we have a string variable x='print(5)', eval(x) will run print(5), i.e. print 5 on the screen.
As mentioned by @daleif,  this function may help us build macros programatically. We may firstly generate a set of code strings by program, and then run it.
Seems that csname can not do it, it can only deal with names; when there are arguments in the string, it fails.
A simple example is:
we already have a command
\newcommand{\test}[2][AA]{This is #1; That is #2.}

And we may have a way to generate a string, a simple one is:
\string\test[A]\string{B\string}

which will output a string:
\test[A]{B}

The question is: is there any way to make this string  a command so that we can run it?

Look for \csname. Or have a look into expl3.

rescan tokens ..?

If you make a complete example, small and compilable, we can try to help.

What does "equivalet to" mean here? On the one hand output \test[A]{B} might be the result of typesetting which you see in the output file/in the .pdf-file. On the other hand the focus of macro programming and processing macro arguments is on tokens. So what one needs to know for macro programming is what tokens the strings (after expansion) consist of. For example \{ is a macro (which in recent LaTeX distributions is expansion-protected) which expands to a bunch of tokens for switching font and selecting a character from a font for placing it inside the box whose content is being typeset.

@UlrichDiez In python, there is a function eval() to run a string. For example, x='print(5)', eval(x). That's what I want to do. I  edited my post.

@XLeo scantokens is the closest to that (but as Ulrich commented under my answer you are making it seem more complicated by suggesting your original string has \{ but you really want \string{ (ie the character { as a string. \{ does not make a { it is a complicated procedure selecting fomts and finally typesetting via a \chardef token and it never expands to a { characer token.

@XLeo I assumed that things are to go into that direction. The point is: In TeX at the level of macro programming things are about so-called tokens, not just characters. Characters exist in the .tex-input-file. TeX reads the input file and tokenizes and afterwards in TeX you have tokens. Tokens exist during the (La)TeX-run. Thus at the processing stage of expanding expandable tokens, e.g., macros, the concept of string is ambiguous in LaTeX. A string could be considered an arbitrary sequence of tokens. It could also be a sequence of explicit non-active character tokens.


The e-tex primitive \scantokens is equivalent to writing the string out to a temporary file and then inputting it again so it is re-parsed as tex tokens. It uses an internal buffer rather than actually opening a file on the filesystem.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\test}[2][AA]{This is #1; That is #2.}

\edef\strtest{\string\test[A]\string{B\string}}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\strtest}

\scantokens\expandafter{\strtest}

\end{document}


as requested in comments, a version with arguments

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\test}[2][AA]{This is #1; That is #2.}

\edef\strtest{\string\test[A]\string{B\string}}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\strtest}

\scantokens\expandafter{\strtest}

\edef\Usetest[#1]#2{ \string\test[#1]\string{#2\string} }

\texttt{\Usetest[A]{B}}

\scantokens\expandafter{\Usetest[A]{B}}

\end{document}


Could one use this to build macros programically? Fx if one is given the number of arguments from user input, and then one adds relevant {#x} to a string that in the end will be the body of the macro? I think I saw something about this in Interface3 but forgot where.

@daleif well you have to use it with care (it bites the unwary) but yes it's what things like xpatch do to redefine commands after making changes

Is using a str_case stack to define macros in my experimental reimplemtation of \DeclarePairedDelimiter, it does the job, but seemed inefficient.

I guess with \edef\strtest{\string\test[A]\{B\}} as in the question \scantokens\expandafter{\strtest} doesn't work out. ;-)

@UlrichDiez I took what (I assumed) the OP meant rather than what was written. (\{ could have been defined to expand to a catcode 12 { but it isn't:-)

I just tried a little complicate way to accept arguments: \edef\Usetest#1#2{ \string\test[#1]\string{#2\string} }, then \scantokens\expandafter{\Usetest[{A}{B}}. However, the output is:  This is [; thats A ]B, Seems that \test does not  get the arguments rights? Is there any way to improve it?

sorry I can't guess what you intend that to do, it defines \Usetest to take two normal {..}{..} arguments as you have edef\Usetest#1#2 so the arguments are [ and A  perhaps you meant  \edef\UseTest[#1]#2{\string\test[#1]\string{#2\string}} @XLeo

@DavidCarlisle I tried \edef\Usetest[#1]#2{ \string\test[#1]\string{#2\string} } too. The output of \scantokens\expandafter{\Usetest[A]{B}} is still: This is [; thats A ]B.

@XLeo you need no space after the { so the \expandafter applies to \UseTest not a space

@XLeo updated answer

@DavidCarlisle Your are right! works now.  Thank you!! Sorry for late reply. I copy everything to a new file to check what happened.

You can have LaTeX read and tokenize macro arguments from the .tex-input-file in verbatim category code régime and save such "verbatim strings" away as macros. Then you can have LaTeX expand these macros and retokenize things via \scantokens:
\NewDocumentCommand\VerbDef{m}{%
  \begingroup\catcode`\^^I=12 \InnerVerbDef{#1}%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand\InnerVerbDef{m+v}{\endgroup\newcommand#1{#2}}%
\newcommand\Myfirstofone[1]{#1}%
\begingroup
\VerbDef\Percent|%|%
\VerbDef\Groupend|\Myfirstofone{\endgroup}|%
\edef\RescanExpanded{%
  \endgroup
  \noexpand\NewDocumentCommand\noexpand\RescanExpanded{m}{%
    \begingroup
    \newlinechar=\endlinechar
    \noexpand\scantokens\noexpand\expanded{{\Groupend##1\Percent}}%
  }%
}%
\RescanExpanded

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}[2][AA]{This is #1; That is #2.}

\begin{document}

\VerbDef\Stringmacro{\test[A]{B}}%

The string is: \RescanExpanded{\string\verb|\Stringmacro|}

The result of carrying out is: \RescanExpanded{\Stringmacro}

\VerbDef\OtherStringmacro{\verb*|\LaTeX is weird!|}%

The string is: \RescanExpanded{\string\verb*+\OtherStringmacro+}

The result of carrying out is: \RescanExpanded{\OtherStringmacro}

\end{document}


\scantokens⟨general text⟩ is like immediately writing all the tokens that form the ⟨general text⟩ unexpanded to external text file via
\immediate\openout\SomeFile MyFile.txt %
\immediate\write\SomeFile{\unexpanded{⟨balanced text⟩}}%
\immediate\closeout\SomeFile
and afterwards using
\input MyFile.txt %
for having TeX focus its eyes on that external text file.
(Unlike with \write with \scantokens character translation from TeX's internal character representation scheme to the computer-platform's character encoding and conversion to ^^-notation do not take place when the \write-part is done. Unlike with \input with \scantokens character translation from the computer platform's character encoding to TeX's internal character representation scheme does not take place when due to the \input-part reading and hereby preprocessing lines of input is done.)
There are some subtleties with \scantokens:

Like with \write a space character is appended when writing characters that form the name of a control word token.
Like with \write the result of writing a control sequence token also depends on the current value of the integer parameter \escapechar.
Like with \write writing explicit character tokens of category 6(parameter), e.g., #6, yields two instances of the character in question. (Colloquially this is called hash-doubling.)
Like with \write the \newlinechar-mechanism is taken into account.
When TeX's eyes turn the focus to the file as if \input had been applied, the state of the reading apparatus is switched to state N (new line) so that spaces/characters of category code 10(space) at the begin of the line are ignored and a subsequent new line yields inserting the token \par into the token stream. (With the example above \Myfirstofone{\endgroup} is used for having the reading apparatus switch to state M (middle of line) when encountering } and thus not skipping spaces that might make the begin of \RescanExpanded's expanded argument.)
While reading lines from the "file", the \endlinechar-game is done as usual. (With the example above a % is appended to \RescanExpanded's expanded argument. That % usually is taken for a comment character and with the last line of the "file" prevents the endline-character appended by TeX from being tokenized.)
When reaching the end of the file or when encountering \endinput the tokens currently held by the token parameter \everyeof are inserted into the token stream.
(If you don't want this, then with the example above you can try
\VerbDef\Percent|\begingroup\everyeof{\endgroup}%|%
instead of \VerbDef\Percent|%|%.)


In your comment from September 24, 2024, 16:47:38Z you ask:

Thanks, this works great! Is the \VerbDef defined here "stronger" than the simple \string? what is missed by \string?

\VerbDef and \string are different approaches for obtaining explicit character tokens rather than control sequence tokens. They focus on different stages of TeX's workflow of producing and processing tokens.
Think of TeX as a living organism. TeX looks at the .tex input file line by line with its eyes. TeX stuffs characters into its mouth that roughly correspond to the characters it sees in in the line. The mouth chews up the stream of characters it receives into bites, so-called tokens. These can be control sequence tokens or character tokens. The tokens then go through the gullet. In the gullet, expandable tokens and their arguments are replaced by other constellations of tokens in a process of regurgitation. Then the tokens end up in TeX's stomach. Here the tokens are directives or arguments of directives and their effect depends on what TeX's stomach is currently doing when the tokens requested by it arrive. For example, writing to external text files or to the screen takes place in the stomach. Defining macros and the like takes place in the stomach. (So control sequence tokens can come into being without denoting something that is already defined/that already has a meaning. Maybe the meaning gets assigned in TeX's stomach.) Typesetting takes place in the stomach, i.e. setting boxes, placing boxes on text pages, placing text pages into the .pdf output file that is to contain the document.
Assume the .tex-input file contains the line \string\LaTeX.
The eyes see these lines and put characters (not character tokens!) \, s, t, r, i, n, g, \, L, a, T, e, X into the mouth.
The mouth chews and sends the tokens \string and  \LaTeX down the gullet.
The gullet finds the control word token \string to be expandable. In the stage of expansion, in the gullet, the effect of \string is removing \string and the following token, \LaTeX, from the token stream and inserting character-token-representation of the name of that subsequent token into the token stream, i.e., the character tokens \12, L12, a12, T12, e12, X12. The subscript 12 indicates that these character tokens are of category 12(other) and have no special effect in typesetting. They don't cause TeX to switch the typesetting mode to math-mode or to leave math-mode as $3 or any other explicit character token of category 3(math shift) would do. They are not taken for control sequence tokens.
So \string, after reading from the .tex-input file and tokenizing already took place, in the stage of expansion,  affects a single token.
\VerbDef is a different approach. \VerbDef first gathers a control sequence token. Then it changes the category code régime so that the mouth from each single character produces a single explicit character token of unspectacular category. Then—by reading from the .tex-input-file and tokenizing characters—a single explicit character token is gathered which serves as verbatim delimiter. Then—by reading from the .tex-input-file and tokenizing characters—more explicit character tokens are gathered until again encountering the token which forms the verbatim-delimiter. The tokens gathered this way form the so-called verbatim-argument. (Often you find verbatim-delimiters |12...|12 or the like. Braces form an exception of the rule of the first and the second delimiter needing to be the same—when the left verbatim-delimiter is found to be {1, then the right verbatim-delimiter is to be the matching }2.) Then \VerbDef defines the gathered control sequence token to be a macro whose replacement text is formed by the gathered explicit character tokens of unspectacular category that form the verbatim-argument.
The advantage is that in the .tex-input-file you don't need to put \string before each sequence of characters that in the mouth of TeX under usual category-code-régime would get tokenized as a(n expandable) control sequence token.
The disadvantage is that this works out only when the tokens forming \VerbDef's verbatim-argument come into being via reading and tokenizing lines/characters of a .tex-input-file so that their coming-into-being with the right category is ensured.
\string has its effect in TeX's gullet, when expandable tokens get expanded, at a time when tokens already got created by the mouth. \string in the gullet causes a token to be replaced by the representation \12 of the escape character (usually \) and its "name" in tems of explicit character tokens of category 12(other).
\VerbDef at the time of gathering the replacement text already causes the mouth to only produce explicit character tokens of unspectacular category rather than producing all kinds of tokens (control sequence tokens, character tokens of whatsoever category).
When you go the \string-route, some of the characters that were typed into the .tex-input-file might not be considered. E.g., TeX's mouth ignores space characters that follow something that got tokenized as a control word token or as explicit space token (explicit character token of character code 32, 32 denoting the space character in TeX's internal character representation-scheme, and category 10(space)). These space characters don't make it into tokens. Thus they cannot be retrieved by "stringifying" tokens. E.g., encountering two subsequent carriage-return characters of category code 5(new line) inserted at the ends of lines due to the \endlinechar-mechanism at the time of tokenization yields a token \par, so retrieving ends of lines/retrieving two subsequent carriage-return-characters that occurred in the .tex-input file by stringifying tokens is not possible.
Besides, the result of \string (like the result of \detokenize) depends on the value of \escapechar. Usually the value of \escapechar is 92 which denotes the backslash character. If you say \escapechar=65 whereby 65 denotes the character A, then the tokens \string\LaTeX in TeX's gullet get replaced by the tokens A12L12 a12T12e12X12—there is A12 instead of the usual \12.
\string produces explicit character tokens of category 12(other). [Exception: Spaces delivered due to "stringifying" explicit character tokens of character code 32 and spaces occurring in names of control sequences are represented by explicit character tokens of character code 32 (32 denotes the space character in TeX's internal character representation scheme) and category 10(space). You can use \csname..\endcsname to produce control sequence tokens whose names contain space characters.]
\VerbDef only changes categories of some special characters like backslash or hash or percent or dollar or hat or underscore etc. Categories of characters that are to be considered unspectacular are left unchanged.
Thus, when typesetting directly instead of passing things on to \scantokens, the outcome with \string may differ from the outcome of \VerbDdef when it comes to processing .tex-input files containing utf-8-characers/multibyte-characters in a traditional 8-bit-TeX-engine using the package inputenc where some characters/bytes that might be parts of multibyte-characters are made active and defined to "look" at subsequent characters/bytes...

Thanks, this works great! Is the\VerbDef defined here "stronger" than  the simple \string? what is missed by \string?

The most simple solution is to define \eval as "do nothing special" and \print as running \detokenize TeX primitive. Try this:
\def\eval#1{#1}
\def\print#1{{\tt\detokenize{#1}}}

\def\test[#1]#2{This is #1; That is #2.}

The string is: \print{\test[A]{B}}.

The result is: \eval{\test[A]{B}}

\bye

But there is a little problem: note the space after \test if it is printed. The \detokenize primitive adds spaces after each control sequence. If you want print exactly what is written in the source file, the "catcode dancing" has to be used in the \print macro.
